# Business layer objects inherit from data layer objects

Tags: .net, design-patterns, architecture

Reviewing the architecture of a legacy application, I have found out that 3-layers pattern is used. The thing is that the domain or business classes inherit from data layer classes, what I have ever seen before. I always reference the data layer objects inside business classes to call them.

I can't see the purpose of implementing the architecture that way, I think it's breaking the separating of concerns, but I don't know if I'm missing something.

Have you ever came across something similar? Is there a good justification of why or why not doing this inheritance?

Comment: This would allow the UI to directly access the data layer.  Could be a good thing or a bad thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The thing is that the domain or business classes inherit from the data layer classes...is there a good justification of why or why not doing this inheritance

If you want to have a *clean* separation between your business layer & data layer (which any good, flexible system will) then this approach definitely smells to me.

The only justification I could give for this type of inheritance is that there must be a guarantee that the backend won't ever change change and the DAL will always use the same definitions as the domain. Generally with DDD the ubiquitous language side of things is constrained to the domain and shouldn't really be a concern in the DAL.

In summary, I would say it's not a great approach with regards to flexibility. However, I couldn't say whether or not it's a *bad* design because it all depends on the context of that specific system.

Answer (score 0):

As you have said, it is a legacy application. Therefore the architecture must not following today's expectation, especially for maintainability. Furthermore, seems like the code does not has test units.

There is many disadvantages for the current architecture. However from business perspective, the design is valid for CRUD operations and stored-procedures databases logics. Normally in CRUD operation, the process flow is defined as this:

input (UI) -> insert to DAL

request (UI) -> get records from DAL -> return to UI

Which makes the separation of concern from BLL and DAL seems overkill (my peers actually said this). Moreover when your data storage has its own logic (stored procedures), the flow directly goes to DAL without BLL. So it is valid to remove BLL at all.

For more information about this different vision of architecture, there is [an interesting article here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/02/09/IsLayeringWorththeMapping),